# Using Regex to extract decimal numbers from arrays on Snowflake

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The column ('DATA') I want to extract the decimal from is in the following format:

{
"unit": "Miles",
"value": 59290.6
}

I've tried the following code by I get a null...

```
regexp_substr(DATA, '\{\d+.\d+\}') AS RECORDED_DISTANCE
```

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: "Regex to extract decimal numbers from arrays". What is your input array?

Comment: So this is found in the column titled DATA: 



{ "unit": "Miles", "value": 59290.6 }                                                   I want to extract just the decimal from it.

Comment: Try this: `\d+\.\d+`. This will gives you `59290.6`. If this is not what you want, please specify your expected output.

Comment: I get a null when I do this.... put in single speech marks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244640/discussion-between-avinash-and-youngboyvba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just mean to access the `value` element?

```
select
    data:value as record_distance
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Still confused as to why none of my regexp_substr statements work though.

Comment: Use double backslashes on the digit matches to make that work. I.e. `regexp_substr(data, '\\d+\.\\d+')`

Comment: Thank you. Works now. Why is that the case here?

Comment: Because the regex string is double parsed. The sql parser and  the regex engine both read the string. So `\\` gets a single `\` past the sql parser, which is then readable to the regex. If you put this into a stored proc you might have the escape it all again.